# Non unique homography matrices for planar decomposition?

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, geometry

I have 2 images of a planar surface and I want to determine its normal. I was able to find matching points and then solve the least squares problem to get a homography matrix between them.

With this https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00174036/document (pg 7) says you can decompose it to the form H = R + t N. The only problem is that H can be scaled and is not unique. How can I ensure I have the right homography matrix?

--- EDIT ---

It does appear to be an affine transformation, but in another text (*An Invitation to 3D Vision* pg 138) it gives an example of this decomposition with just an arbitrary 3x3 as the homography and it works

[image]

My code gets the correct answer on this, but every homography I calculate results in a normal that is always pointing strait up...

Comment: There seems to be a word missing in your first sentence, possibly “have”. I suggest you point out *where* in that 94 page document the statement you refer to is being made.

Comment: Good call, thank you I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Page 6 of that text writes:

> <sup>c</sup>T<sub>d</sub> = 
>   [<sup>c</sup>R<sub>d</sub> <sup>c</sup>t<sub>d</sub>]
>            
>   [  0   1  ]

so the text at that point appears to be dealing with an *affine* transformation only, with the bottom right coordinate normalized to 1.

Comment: Thanks, that is true. But it looks like later it does it for the more general form (like the example I added above). I normalize the homography by a value and there should be a unique solution, right?